# Tengo un error al llamar mi controlador desde javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, visual-studio

Estoy programando un botón el cuál necesita comunicarse con mi controller para acceder a un método que tengo en el mismo. El problema que tengo es que me está dando error y no encuentro específicamente dónde es, espero me puedan ayudar.

Mi función es la siguiente:

```
function GenerarRecord(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/ModeloGrid',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
};
```

Este se supone que iría a mi Home Controller y acceder a éste método:

```
public JsonResult ModeloGrid()
    {
        ReporteCAS reporteCAS = new ReporteCAS();
        return Json("success");
    }
```

pero en lugar de eso me da este error:

[image: 1]

Como pueden ver es un error en mi función de ajax aunque aún no detecto bien qué parte es.

Pequeña corrección, añado código de mi Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Coloca el archivo controller entero (el homeController.cs) y el program.cs

Answer (score 1):

```
function GenerarRecord(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/HomeController/ModeloGrid', // Aquí el problema, especifica el controller.
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Hice la corrección pero me sigue dando el mismo error. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Varias: 1. Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que tienes en el `startup.cs` y `program.cs`. 2. Encima del `ModeloGrid` coloca el atributo `[HttpGet()]` 3. ¿Estás usando el mismo puerto?

Comment: No se debe colocar el sufijo Controller, la ruta correcta es /Home/ModeloGrid

Comment: Ya agregué el código de mi program, la parte de [HttpGet()] ya la agregué tambien y todo está dentro de un proyecto en visual studio de Aplicación Web MVC. Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Primero para confirmar correctamente la llamada al contralor puedes usar Url.Action:

```
function GenerarRecord(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ModeloGrid", "Home")',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
};
```

Tú código esta bien pero solo te mostré una alternativa, que crea dinámicamente la url:

```
function GenerarRecord(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/ModeloGrid',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
};
```

En la parte del controlador tienes que corregir, la parte que pones *JsonResult* cambialo por *ActionResult* y la forma de retornar el Json mejora el formato, asi:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ModeloGrid()
{
    ReporteCAS reporteCAS = new ReporteCAS();
    return Json(new { mensaje = "success" });
}
```

Comment: Ya hice las correcciones, al principio creí que se había solucionado porque no me mandaba errores la consola (Cambiando lo del Url.Action), el problema era que al validar el elementos el url aparecía vacío (url: '') y por este motivo no daba error, no estaba direccionando al controlador. Lo regresé a como estaba con la url directa y me manda el mismo error. Ya corregí de igual forma en el controller lo del actionresult y eso. No sé bien porqué no entra al controlador y me manda error.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí les dejo el cómo se ve el código y cómo me lo muestra en los elementos al inspeccionarlo.

Código:

```
function GenerarRecord() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ModeloGrid", "Home")',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

Cuando lo checo en inspeccionar:

```
function GenerarRecord() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

Entonces no se redirecciona y al ponerlo como lo tenía me sigue mandando el mismo error.

Comment: Esta es la seccion de respuestas, para agregar  mas detalles a tu pregunta puedes editarla.